# PHP Upload system not moving file from temp to specified directory

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've tried to create a basic PHP/MySQL picture upload system using the W3Schools example as a reference, however I cannot for the life of me work out why the uploaded file is not being copied to the destination specified.

Here is my PHP code:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$uploads_dir = 'img/houses';

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       $uploads_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . $uploads_dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
   }
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

And here is the HTML upload form:

```
<form action="uploadHousePic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Image: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        <br><br>
        Price: &pound; <input type="text" name="Price">
        <br><br>
        Type of house: <input type="text" name="Type">
        <br><br>
        Location: <input type="text" name="Location">
        <br><br>
        Description: <textarea rows="6" cols="60" input type="text" name="Description"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Finally, I have the destination code on another php page where the picture + info will be inserted:

```
<?php
        // this is used to connect to the database on the mysql server called houselist
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();// if there is a problem with the connection and it can't connect it will display this error to the user.
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_house_info");//this setups the query to be used in order to gather the data to be displayed on the page. it will select all the data from the tbl_house_page.

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {//this then will run a loop and fetch all the results from the database in an array and display them in order row by row.
          echo '<div class="housepost">';//this is used to add the format of the web page that was used.
          echo '<img src="img/houses/', $row['Image'],'" width="270px" height="190px" alt=""  />';// this line adds the image to the div and adds in the destination of the image, the image will have been placed here from the upload and now adding in the file name from the database it will display the full image on the page.
          echo '<h2>' , '£' ,$row['Price'] , '</h2>' , '<p>'. $row['Type'] , '</p>' , '<p>' . $row['Location'] , '</p>' , '<p>' , $row['Description'] , '</p>';// this will then add some more formatting as well as displaying the other columns of data which are the price, type, location and destination on the web page to the user.
          echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is for a College project that I am working on, so I wanted to try and figure it out for myself; but when both you and your teacher cannot find the problem something is wrong...

Thanks :)

Comment: Please check out one of my answers of uploading files some are much more dynamic and shorter than this method

Comment: @user3628161 Are You developing on UBUNTU or WIN or MacOs? :)

Comment: I'm developing on a Windows 32 machine (College computer) running both Apache and MySQL from my memory stick using Xampp's portable version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if max file size and max post size in php.ini are big enough! :)

```
file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = xxxM 

post_max_size = xxxM
```

For 70% it's bad config.

EDIT: Restart server (Xampp, apache, wampp or any other) :)

Comment: 'file_uploads' are on in the php.ini file, but 'upload_max_filesize = 2M' and 'post_max_size = 8M'. I changed both values to '20M', but sadly still no luck. Thanks for your quick reply also :)

Comment: And I'm guessing that the file You are uploading is smaller than 20MB. :)
Damn - that was the most common problem with my apps.
Have You restarted the apache or other server You are working on? :) Sorry for my questions but I wanna be sure. :)

Comment: Yeah it's only 3.3MB! I have tried restarting both Apache and MySQL and still no luck. Not a problem, you help is greatly appreciated. It's just so weird how everything we have tried is still not working. It must be some silly mistake I'm missing but I just can't find it. This also works for a text-file upload system that I have made on another page, so it's just when pictures are involved... :/

Comment: Could You please check edit of my answer and post var_dump of $e ? :)
of course if the functions will throw an exception :)

Comment: Well I'll be dammed, just restarted Xampp again just to see if it would work and it is! That's so strange. Thanks for your help (and everyone else as well) :P

Comment: :D Good for You! :) Told Ya!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Change your path from `$uploads_dir = 'img/houses';` to `$uploads_dir = 'img/houses/';` 
Also check whether you have the write privileges for this directory.

You can also use `is_writable()` function to check whether writable.

Refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: Just tried the 'is_writable()' function and the directory I am trying to write to does have write permissions enabled. Furthermore, changing the directory from 'img/houses' to 'img/houses/' doesn't seem to work either... Thanks for your quick reply nonetheless :P

Comment: any errors received in code ? or whether the `move_uploaded_file` part been executed for sure ?

Comment: you getting message `echo "Stored in: " ...` ?

Comment: No, that message isn't being displayed actually... Strange.

Comment: If you are in windows then this shouldn't be the directory format na ?